# LLVM: Differentiate between 0- and externally-initialized bss symbol

Tags: llvm, elf, llvm-c++-api

I'm working with llvm to process elf x86 binaries.

I've got the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

int main(void) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello World! %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

which compiles down to the following assembly code:

```s
    .text
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .file   "fprintf.c"
    .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:                                # %entry
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    sub rsp, 16
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    mov rdi, qword ptr [stdout]
    mov edx, dword ptr [x]
    movabs  rsi, offset .L.str
    mov al, 0
    call    fprintf
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 16
    pop rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa rsp, 8
    ret
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end0-main
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .type   .L.str,@object                  # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Hello World! %d\n"
    .size   .L.str, 17

    .type   x,@object                       # @x
    .bss
    .globl  x
    .p2align    2
x:
    .long   0                               # 0x0
    .size   x, 4

    .ident  "clang version 13.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git f5ba3eea6746559513af7ed32db8083ad52661a3)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
    .addrsig
    .addrsig_sym fprintf
    .addrsig_sym stdout
    .addrsig_sym x
```

The interesting part here is the `.bss` section.

Both `x` and `stdout` are declared in the `.bss` section, with the difference being that `x` is initialized to `0`, but not `stdout`. `stdout` is defined in `stdio.h`.

Now to my issue: Is there a way I can differentiate between `x`, which should be initialized with `0`, and `stdout`, which should be initialized somewhere else (it's the linkers job).

Currently I have the following code (irrelevant parts stripped):

```cpp
DataRefImpl SymbImpl = GlobalSymRef.getRawDataRefImpl();
// get symbol
ELF64LEObjectFile *ObjFile = getObjFile();
auto SymbOrErr = Elf64LEObjFile->getSymbol(SymbImpl);
assert(SymbOrErr && "Global symbol not found");
auto Symb = SymbOrErr.get();

// Symb->isExternal() is true for both x and stdout

for (section_iterator SecIter : ObjFile->sections()) {
  if (SecIter->containsSymbol(GlobalSymRef)) {
    if (SecIter->isBSS()) {
      // true for both x and stdout
      // is there a way to differentiate between the two?
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I was able to explain my issue :) I'd appreciate all help

Comment: I guess that tag really doesn't fit too well. I'll remove it. Thanks. @DanielLangr

Comment: I'd start with `objdump`/`elfdump` to figure out the difference between these symbols.

Comment: Ok so I had a look at the `.bss` section in the final executable, and there does not seem to be a difference between the two. There's no data except their name in there (kinda makes sense, since all symbols in there are 0-initialized). Not sure if it's possible to find a difference between the two just looking at the bss section.